# Blank row after subtotal on grid view (SQL)

Tags: sql-server-2014

I am attempting to add a blank row and subtotal into a grid view of a table.  I have managed to add the subtotal row, but no luck on the blank row.  The blank row is to separate the months.  My code is as below, if anyone can help I would appreciate it. If you could also tell me how to bold the subtotal row (if it's possible) that would also be great.

There is quite a lot of data, but in brief some sample data and output would look like:

```html
DATA 
Period Production
31-Jul-15 15
31-Jul-15 8
31-Jul-15 7
31-Jul-15 9
31-Aug-15 10
31-Aug-15 5
31-Aug-15 12
31-Aug-15 18
 
OUTPUT REQUIRED 
Period Production
31-Jul-15 15
31-Jul-15 8
31-Jul-15 7
31-Jul-15 9
***Monthly Total 39
 
31-Aug-15 10
31-Aug-15 5
31-Aug-15 12
31-Aug-15 18
***Monthly Total 45
```

Code currently is:

```
select
d.period,
CASE WHEN d.period is null then 'Grand Total' 
                   ELSE coalesce (d.description,'MONTHLY TOTAL') end AS Description,
sum(d.Prod_Qty) as 'Production Made',
round(sum(d.TotalTonnes),2) as Tonnes,
sum(d.TotalHrs) as Hours,
round(sum(d.TotalTonnes)/sum(d.TotalHrs),2) as 'Tonnes per Hour',
sum(d.ProdTime) as 'Production Time',
round(sum(d.TotalTonnes)/sum(d.ProdTime),2) as 'Prod Time per Tonne'

from
(
SELECT DISTINCT
       EOMONTH(FWT_DAILYPRODUCTION.TransDate) AS Period,
       FWT_DAILYPRODUCTION.Prod_Qty,
       FWT_PROD_MACHINES.Description,
       STOCK_ITEMS.CUBIC, 
       STOCK_ITEMS.X_BEATS, 
       STOCK_ITEMS.Weight, 
       FWT_DAILYPRODUCTION.Prod_Qty * STOCK_ITEMS.Weight / 1000 as TotalTonnes,
       (select sum(FWT_LABOUR_LINES.ProdTime) from FWT_LABOUR_LINES where
       FWT_DAILYPRODUCTION.SEQNO = FWT_LABOUR_LINES.HDR_SEQNO) as ProdTime, 
       (select sum(FWT_LABOUR_LINES.TotalHrs) from FWT_LABOUR_LINES where
       FWT_DAILYPRODUCTION.SEQNO = FWT_LABOUR_LINES.HDR_SEQNO) as TotalHrs




FROM FWT_DAILYPRODUCTION FWT_DAILYPRODUCTION
     FULL OUTER JOIN FWT_LABOUR_LINES FWT_LABOUR_LINES ON 
     (FWT_LABOUR_LINES.HDR_SEQNO = FWT_DAILYPRODUCTION.SEQNO)
      FULL OUTER JOIN FWT_JOB_COST_HDR FWT_JOB_COST_HDR ON 
     (FWT_JOB_COST_HDR.SEQNO = FWT_DAILYPRODUCTION.JOBNO)
      FULL OUTER JOIN FWT_PROD_MACHINES FWT_PROD_MACHINES ON 
     (FWT_PROD_MACHINES.SEQNO = FWT_JOB_COST_HDR.PROD_MACHINE)
      FULL OUTER JOIN FWT_JOB_TYPE FWT_JOB_TYPE ON 
     (FWT_JOB_TYPE.SEQNO = FWT_JOB_COST_HDR.JOB_TYPE)
      FULL OUTER JOIN FWT_JOB_STATUS FWT_JOB_STATUS ON 
     (FWT_JOB_STATUS.SEQNO = FWT_JOB_COST_HDR.STATUS)
      FULL OUTER JOIN FWT_BILLOMAT FWT_BILLOMAT ON 
     (FWT_BILLOMAT.BILLCODE = FWT_JOB_COST_HDR.BILLCODE)
      FULL OUTER JOIN STOCK_ITEMS STOCK_ITEMS ON 
     (STOCK_ITEMS.STOCKCODE = FWT_BILLOMAT.OUTPUT)
      FULL OUTER JOIN STOCK_LOCATIONS STOCK_LOCATIONS ON 
     (STOCK_LOCATIONS.LOCNO = FWT_JOB_COST_HDR.LOCNO)

WHERE 
      ( EOMONTH(FWT_DAILYPRODUCTION.TransDate) >= DATEADD(MM, DATEDIFF(MM, 0, GETDATE())-13, 0))
       AND FWT_JOB_COST_HDR.PROD_MACHINE IN (24,19,20,21,22,23,12)

)d      

Group by
rollup(d.period,d.description)


ORDER BY 
  d.period desc,
    d.description desc
```

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: sql-server-2014, have updated the tag.  Cheers

Comment: Can you provide some sample data, result you are getting and expected output?

Comment: Hi Mangal, have added some sample data and output to the post.  Note there is quite a bit of data so have just added a very small snippet.

Comment: This kind of formatting should really be done by the client, not the sql server.

Comment: Vladimir, If it helps I am writing SQL script in a dashboard, drawing information from tables.